# Installing Apache server

Tags: apache

How to install Apache server on your computer? I have downloaded the file from here: http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi but there is no installation file in this archive. What file should I be looking for or is there some other way to go about it completely and I am being totally wrong?

Comment: You need to read the documentation, there are full installation instructions for all supported operating systems. If you get stuck then come back with a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the documentation : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're Windows user, I would like to suggest you to install **XAMPP** from 
(apache, mysql and php5) 
https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

If you're Linux user, type following command (Ubuntu or Debian)

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
```